# Does Direct2D have CompositingModeCopy like GDI+?

Tags: direct2d

I am trying to move my virtual white board application from gdi+ to direct2d.
Perviously I used Graphics::SetCompositingMode(CompositingModeCopy) to "eraser" function, but I can't find similary interface in direct2d.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`D2D1_COMPOSITING_MODE_SOURCE_COPY`, which requires Direct2D 1.1 (Windows 8+, or Windows 7 SP1 w/ Platform Update)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446995(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, pairing `ID2D1RenderTarget::PushAxisAlignedClip` and `ID2D1RenderTarget::Clear()` can be used to "erase" a rectangular region. Works on Windows 7 RTM.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742775(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JamesSunderland You know you can vote/select his answer.